# App size is increased while attaching google play services using new version of Admob Ads?

Tags: android, mobile, admob

**My app size is very less (200kb)** while develop using admob older version ads.
Now older versions ads are deprecated and stop serving from August 2014 onwards.

So i need to add new admob adds using google play services.
**Then my app size is incresed to 1.15 mb.**

1. How to reduce my app size using new admob ads ?
2. App size is important. please tell me any alternate solution to show adds with less app size

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even when you consider app size as important, why bother when barely above 1MB?

Comment: I need to add adds also. Please give me any alternate solution.

Comment: You haven't answered my question: why are you considering 1MB as an app size as bad? That is nothing compared to other apps

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer... also have you considered the simple fact that the library just increased in size and therefore your app size increased as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wide question. Instead Admobs, i can give you some ideas on how you can decrease the .apk size and app performance:

- There might be some images you loaded into environment but never used, delete them.
- Try to use .png format for images for smaller size. Especially if you have many image files with large sizes, you can use some tools to reduce size without loosing the quality. Youcan use [Opti PNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)
- Remove unused resources in your res directory, such as unused layouts, drawables and colors.

Above are the main matters cause such large size of .apk files. Following to instructions will help you.

**Note:** With Admobs ads, 500-600Kb and likely above with library files and coding will be normal file size for any apk from minumum implementation and up to higher, therefore, you can't really decrease on ads to reduce size, try with other assets as i mentioned above. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you brother to share your answer. But i am already do all above ideas. By use previous admob library i do app size is below 200kb. Now onwards we use google play service library instead of admob library it contains 1.15mb.

Answer (score 1):

Use admob jar to decrease your app size.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/DownloadGoogleAdMobAdsSdk601jar.htm